# focus an element in css

Tags: html, css, input, focus

Is it possible to make an input focused that is hidden after displaying it.
I have an checkbox:

```
<div class="search">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" >
    <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Type in...">
    <label for="toggle"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></label>
</div>
```

After checking checkbox the search input appears.

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ input.search-input {
    width: 100px;
    opacity:1;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    user-focus: normal;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

Is it possible to make in pure css this input to be focused after it appears?
I need only pure css, i know that it is possible to make with javascript.

Comment: you have 2 inputs with same `id="toggle"` attr, by the way :)

Comment: yes i know, that was just my tests :D

Comment: yes i know but it is a task in school so they don't allowed me to use javascript :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no way to do this with CSS alone.

Just a note, if you were to use jQuery, you could utilize a rather trivial on change event like this:

```
$('#toggle').on('change', function(){
    $('.search-input').focus();
});
```

Edit: I just saw your comment that your school won't allow JS. That's confusing since it's not possible without it. This doesn't really apply, but there is the [HTML5 autofocus attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/autofocus). (doesn't apply because it's simply on page load)

Comment: Hey Max, mind accepting my answer here? Would really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Max! Much appreciated!